# How to use jQuery longclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, long-click

I am using datatables plugin and using this for click:

```
$('.datatable').on('click', 'img#openpli-playlist', function(e) {
    alert("You clicked OPENPLI ICON!");
});
```

Now I need to use jQuery plugin longclick and using this:

```
$('.datatable').longClick(function(e) {
    alert("You clicked OPENPLI ICON!");
},1000);
```

So the problem is how can I add selector to longclick I try this for selector but is not working:

```
$('.datatable img#openpli-playlist').longClick(function(e) {
    alert("You clicked OPENPLI ICON!");
},1000);
```

Can someone give me solution why is this not working?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple fix will be:

```
var tmr = 0;
$(element).mousedown(function () {
  tmr = setTimeout(function () {
    alert("You clicked for 1 second! Wow!");
  }, 1000);
}).mouseup(function () {
  clearTimeout(tmr);
});
```

Now this can be used in delegation too:

```
var tmr = 0;
$(static_parent).on("mousedown", element, function () {
  tmr = setTimeout(function () {
    alert("You clicked for 1 second! Wow!");
  }, 1000);
}).on("mouseup", element, function () {
  clearTimeout(tmr);
});
```

Your solution:

```
var tmr = 0;
$('.datatable').on('mousedown', 'img#openpli-playlist', function(e) {
  tmr = setTimeout(function () {
    alert("You clicked OPENPLI ICON!");
  }, 1000);
}).on('mouseup', 'img#openpli-playlist', function(e) {
  clearTimeout(tmr);
});
```

As an improvement to previous answers, you can distinguish between click and long press in this way:

```js
var tmr = 0;
var islong = 0;

$(element)
  .mousedown(function () {
    tmr = setTimeout(function () {
      // Handle the long-press
      alert("You clicked for 1 second!");
      console.log("You clicked for 1 second!");
      islong = 1;
    }, 1000);
  })
  .mouseup(function () {
    if (islong == 0) {
      // Handle the click
      alert("This is a click!");
      console.log("This is a click!");
    }
    islong = 0;
    clearTimeout(tmr);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks Your Solution is what i need....it is using timer and mouseup and mousedown event...thanks..working perfectly...